# Task Exception Management c#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, async-await, task-parallel-library

I run a solution that contains 2 projects: the app and the sdk.

Through the app I create an instance of the sdk so the app can start. The problem is that when I get an Exception in a part of code running inside of a Task, no Unhandled Exception is thrown so my app keeps running and doesn't realise an unexpected is happening in the SDK.

I am registered to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`'s event in the App and SDK, but as said when the Exception is thrown in a Task, the event handler isn't called.

Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both answers are somewhat (but not fully) complete.

### Asynchronous

The best way to handle a faulted task is to **asynchronously wait** for it to complete using `await`. This will rethrow the original stored exception:

```
try
{
    await task;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // handle exception
}
```

### Synchronous

If you can't do that (or don't want to) you can also use `task.Wait()` which waits synchronously and throws an **`AggregateException` containing the original exception** in `InnerExceptions` or register a continuation that handles it (i.e. `task.ContinueWith(t => // handle exception)`)

### UnobservedTaskException

In .Net 4.0 an unobserved Task exception would bring down the entire process. The `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event was the last option to handle the exception before the crash (very similar to the case of `UnhandledException`). In .Net 4.5 this type of exception no longer crashes the app, **but the event is still raised**.

If you want to crash the app in this case (and I doubt you do) you can set `<ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/>` as Yuval pointed out. You can instead use the event itself to handle the exception which isn't optimal for 2 reasons:

1. .Net decides your task's exception was unobserved only when the task is garbage collected which **could happen anytime** (or never, if you don't release all references to it). Until then you may still handle the exception yourself, so it isn't yet unobserved.
2. You get the exception, but not the task, and it can be difficult to know the real origin of the problem without it.

### Conclusion

Make sure to `await` your tasks to handle exceptions as they occur. Also use `UnobservedTaskException` as a catch all in case you missed a task.

Comment: I'd be glad to understand the part that isn't *fully* correct about my answer

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov a. There's no reason for `Task.Run` specifically. b. "no Unhandled Exception", "This is true if you're using .NET 4.5 or above." this is also true for 4.0. that's what `UnobservedTaskException` is for  c. Crashing the app on an exception isn't the default on 4.0, it's the only option and while the finalizer doesn't crash the app anymore, it does still propagate the exception through the event as before.

Comment: But anyway, it was meant to be more "not fully complete" than "not fully correct" so I changed it.

Comment: I was using `Task.Run` simply to demonstrate the *continuation*, which was the actual purpose. b + c. You're right about the task propagating the exception in both versions, ill correct that.

Comment: thank you very much, I mark this as the answer just cause takes other answers information and give some extra info. But three answers are awesome

Comment: @user3009804 sure.. any time.

Answer (score 3):

When a `Task` throws an unhandled exception, its execution is terminated and you can check for `IsFaulted` and `Exception` properties on the original `Task` object.

More info about those properties [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.isfaulted(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception(v=vs.110).aspx), and there's an article devoted to exception handling in Tasks [on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx)

You also have the `UnobservedTaskException` event on `TaskScheduler`. I've never used it myself, but reading about it, it should be similar to the `UnhandledException` event on `AppDomain`. Check it [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Didn't know about this, Jcl. Will take a look to your response. Thank you very much for it

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that when I get an Exception in a part of code running
>   inside of a Task, no Unhandled Exception is thrown so my app keeps
>   running and doesn't realise an unexpected is happening in the SDK.

That's not entirely correct (thanks to @l3arnon for the correction): `Task` will propagate the exceptions in both .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5, and will fire the `UnobservedTaskException`. The difference between the two is that .NET 4.5 will *quietly* swallow the exception after it fires, as opposed to .NET 4.0 which will crash your process if that event goes unhandled.

You can change back to the .NET 4.0 behavior via your 'app.config`and`ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions`

There are a couple of other ways you can tackle this problem:

1. use `await Task.Run` in your code. `await` will unwrap your exception from inside the task.
2. If you don't want to await and want to use a "Fire and Forget" approach, you can attach a continuation:

   ```
   Task.Run(() => {}).ContinueWith(task => { */ Handle Exceptions here */ },
                                   TaskContinutationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much Yuval, your reply has help me a lot